# Having trouble checking to see if a string is balanced or not

Tags: java, stack

```
package edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy;

import java.util.Stack;

public class Checker {

    char openPara = '(';
    char openBracket = '[';
    char openCurly = '{';
    char openArrow = '<';
    char closePara = ')';
    char closeBracket = ']';
    char closeCurly = '}';
    char closeArrow = '>';

    public boolean checkString(String stringToCheck) {
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < stringToCheck.length(); i++) {
            char c = stringToCheck.charAt(i);
            if (c == openPara || c == openBracket || c == openCurly || c == openArrow) {
                stack.push(c);
                System.out.println(stack);
                ;
            }
            if (c == closePara) {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                } else if (stack.peek() == openPara) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else if (stack.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (c == closeBracket) {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                } else if (stack.peek() == openBracket) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else if (stack.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (c == closeCurly) {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                } else if (stack.peek() == openCurly) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else if (stack.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (c == closeArrow) {
                if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                } else if (stack.peek() == openArrow) {
                    stack.pop();
                } else if (stack.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

I am currently trying to create a program where I check to see if a string is balanced or not. A string is balanced if and only if each opening character: (, {, [, and < have a matching closing character: ), }, ], and > respectively.

What happens is when checking through the string, if an opening character is found, it is pushed into a stack, and it checks to see if there is the appropriate closing character.

If there is a closing character before the opening character, then that automatically means that the string is unbalanced. Also, the string is automatically unbalanced if after going to the next character there is something still inside of the stack.

I tried to use

```
else if (stack.size() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Unbalanced");
                    break;
                }
```

as a way of seeing if the stack still had anything in it, but it still isn't working for me. Any advice on what to do?

For example, if the string input were `()<>{()` then the program should run through like normal until it gets to the single `{` and then the code should realize that the string is unbalanced and output `Unbalanced`.

For whatever reason, my code does not do this.

Comment: What is not working?  Can you give an example?  My advice would be to find the simplest example that does not work, then hand execute it to discover at which point your algorithm goes wrong.

Comment: If you put in (<> it will take the open parenthesis and push it into a stack. What it is supposed to do is look for the closing parenthesis, and if it doesn't find it, leave the ( in the stack. When it gets to `else if (stack.size() > 0)` it is supposed to break out of the loop and tell the user that the string is unbalanced, but it doesn't do that.

Comment: You can't do that until you get to the end of the string.  That's why I say to hand execute this.  If you tried that you'd see that you need to get to the end in order to detect unbalanced parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following logic is flawed (emphasis mine):

> For example, if the string input were `()<>{()` then the program should run through like normal **until it gets to the single `{`** and then the code should realize that the string is unbalanced and output Unbalanced.

In fact, the code can't conclude that the string is unbalanced until it has scanned **the entire string** and established that the `{` has no matching `}`. For all it knows, the full input could be `()<>{()}` and be balanced.

To achieve this, you need to add a check that ensures that the stack is empty after the entire string has been processes. In your example, it would still contain the `{`, indicating that the input is not balanced.

Answer (score 0):

I took a shot at answering this. My solutions returns true if the string is balanced and enforces opening/closing order (ie `({)}` returns false). I started with your code and tried to slim it down.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

public class mamurphy {

  private static final char openPara = '(';
  private static final char openBracket = '[';
  private static final char openCurly = '{';
  private static final char openArrow = '<';
  private static final char closePara = ')';
  private static final char closeBracket = ']';
  private static final char closeCurly = '}';
  private static final char closeArrow = '>';


  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(checkString("{}[]()90<>"));//true
    System.out.println(checkString("(((((())))"));//false
    System.out.println(checkString("((())))"));//false
    System.out.println(checkString(">"));//false
    System.out.println(checkString("["));//false
    System.out.println(checkString("{[(<>)]}"));//true
    System.out.println(checkString("{[(<>)}]"));//false
    System.out.println(checkString("( a(b) (c) (d(e(f)g)h) I (j<k>l)m)"));//true
  }

  public static boolean checkString(String stringToCheck) {
    final Map<Character, Character> closeToOpenMap = new HashMap<>();
    closeToOpenMap.put(closePara, openPara);
    closeToOpenMap.put(closeBracket, openBracket);
    closeToOpenMap.put(closeCurly, openCurly);
    closeToOpenMap.put(closeArrow, openArrow);
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
    final char[] stringAsChars = stringToCheck.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < stringAsChars.length; i++) {
      final char current = stringAsChars[i];
      if (closeToOpenMap.values().contains(current)) {
        stack.push(current); //found an opening char, push it!
      } else if (closeToOpenMap.containsKey(current)) {
        if (stack.isEmpty() || closeToOpenMap.get(current) != stack.pop()) {
          return false;//found closing char without correct opening char on top of stack
        }
      }
    }
    if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      return false;//still have opening chars after consuming whole string
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach:

```
    private static final char[] openParens = "[({<".toCharArray();
    private static final char[] closeParens = "])}>".toCharArray();

    public static boolean isBalanced(String expression){
        Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        for (char c : expression.toCharArray()){
            for (int i = 0; i < openParens.length; i++){
                if (openParens[i] == c){
                    // This is an open - put it in the stack
                    stack.push(c);
                    break;
                }
                if (closeParens[i] == c){
                    // This is a close - check the open is at the top of the stack
                    if (stack.poll() != openParens[i]){
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
```

It simplifies the logic to have two corresponding arrays of open and close symbols. You could also do this with even and odd positions in one array - ie. "{}<>", for example:

```
    private static final char[] symbols = "[](){}<>".toCharArray();

    public static boolean isBalanced(String expression){
        Deque<Character> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        for (char c : expression.toCharArray()){
            for (int i = 0; i < symbols.length; i += 2){
                if (symbols[i] == c){
                    // This is an open - put it in the stack
                    stack.push(c);
                    break;
                }
                if (symbols[i + 1] == c){
                    // This is a close - check the open is at the top of the stack
                    if (stack.poll() != symbols[i]){
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return stack.isEmpty();
    }
```

Note that poll returns null if the stack is empty, so will correctly fail the equality comparison if we run out of stack.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if the string input were ()<>{() then the program should run through like normal **until it gets to the single {** and then the code should realize that the string is unbalanced and output Unbalanced.

It is not clear by your example whether the boundaries can be **nested** like `([{}])`. If they can, that logic will not work, as the whole string has to be consumed to be sure any missing closing-chars aren't at the end, and so, the string cannot be reliably deemed unbalanced at the point you indicate.

Here is my take on your problem:

**BalanceChecker class:**

```
package so_q33378870;

import java.util.Stack;

public class BalanceChecker {

    private final char[] opChars = "([{<".toCharArray();
    private final char[] edChars = ")]}>".toCharArray();

    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="support functions">
    public boolean isOPChar(char c) {
        for (char checkChar : opChars) {
            if (c == checkChar) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEDChar(char c) {
        for (char checkChar : edChars) {
            if (c == checkChar) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //NOTE: Unused.
//  public boolean isBoundaryChar(char c) {
//      boolean result;
//      if (result = isOPChar(c) == false) {
//          return isEDChar(c);
//      } else {
//          return result;
//      }
//  }

    public char getOpCharFor(char c) {
        for (int i = 0; i < edChars.length; i++) {
            if (c == edChars[i]) {
                return opChars[i];
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The character (" + c + ") received is not recognized as a closing boundary character.");
    }
//</editor-fold>

    public boolean isBalanced(char[] charsToCheck) {
        Stack<Character> checkStack = new Stack<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < charsToCheck.length; i++) {
            if (isOPChar(charsToCheck[i])) {
                //beginning char found. Add to top of stack.
                checkStack.push(charsToCheck[i]);
            } else if (isEDChar(charsToCheck[i])) {
                if (checkStack.isEmpty()) {
                    //ending char found without beginning chars on the stack. UNBALANCED.
                    return false;
                } else if (getOpCharFor(charsToCheck[i]) == checkStack.peek()) {
                    //ending char found matches last beginning char on the stack. Pop and continue.
                    checkStack.pop();
                } else {
                    //ending char found, but doesn't match last beginning char on the stack. UNBALANCED.
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        //the string is balanced if and only if the stack is empty at the end.
        return checkStack.empty();
    }

    public boolean isBalanced(String stringToCheck) {
        return isBalanced(stringToCheck.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

**Main class (used for testing):**

```
package so_q33378870;

public class main {

    private static final String[] tests = {
        //Single - Balanced.
        "()",
        //Single - Unbalanced by missing end.
        "(_",
        //Multiple - Balanced.
        "()[]{}<>",
        //Multiple - Unbalanced by missing beginning.
        "()[]_}<>",
        //Nested - Balanced.
        "([{<>}])",
        //Nested - Unbalanced by missing end.
        "([{<>}_)",
        //Endurance test - Balanced.
        "the_beginning (abcd) divider (a[bc]d) divider (a[b{c}d]e) divider (a[b{c<d>e}f]g) the_end"
    };

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BalanceChecker checker = new BalanceChecker();
        for (String s : tests) {
            System.out.println("\"" + s + "\" is " + ((checker.isBalanced(s)) ? "BALANCED!" : "UNBALANCED!"));
        }
    }
}
```